# Views resize after view controller presented IB

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm having a strange Issue. I am presenting a custom view controller. This controller has a square view centered with top, bottom, leading, trailing constraints etc. No warnings. However when I present the controller the view isn't resized until the animation finishes. So it's temporarily too big (as it animates up the screen when presented) but then snaps to the correct size. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Post some sample code, a simplified version of your code. (doesn't have to be all your application code). So that one can execute it and see what is wrong.

Comment: It's all done in interface builder @user1046037

Comment: storyboard screen should be attached then

Comment: How are you doing the animation?  By using one of the predefined transitions from Interface Builder?